# Paging problem with GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, paging

i have a asp.net webpage with a `GridView`

```
<asp:GridView ID="grid_view" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" 
    BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" ForeColor="Black" 
    GridLines="Vertical">
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="adc" HeaderText="Posa No." />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="cde" HeaderText="Unit" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="efg" HeaderText="User" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="hj" HeaderText="Posa Date" />
    </Columns>
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" /> 
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
</asp:GridView>
```

and my code behind is

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Connection"]);
  gridfil();
}


public void gridfil()
{
  con.Open();
  cmd = new SqlCommand("select a,b,c from xyz where approved='sss'", con);
  SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
  SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
  DataSet ds = new DataSet();
  da.Fill(ds);
  grid_view.DataSource = ds;
  grid_view.DataBind();
  //rd.Close();
  da.Dispose();
  cmd.Dispose();
  con.Close();
}

protected void grid_view_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
  grid_view.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
  gridfil();
}
```

My problem is grid view was diplayed but the page indexing not working...
Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your page load code under `!IsPostBack()`

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Connection"]);
        gridfil();
    }
}
```

**Reason:** Whenever you click on Page Number and want to view another page, Page will be postback and your `page load event` fired before `grid_view_PageIndexChanging` and it will rebind the gridview and your event will be lost and it will not fire PageIndexChanging event.

Secondly change this and see the comments

```
protected void grid_view_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
  gridfil(); // First bind the gridview 
  grid_view.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex; // then change the page Index
}
```

Comment: ok its woring Muhammad Akhtar.its in my master page prob.anyway thank u very much...